# How can I use C# and the SslStream class to open a connection with TLS channel binding?

Tags: c#, xmpp, sslstream, sasl-scram

I am attempting to implement SCRAM-SHA-1-PLUS in my XMPP library and I am stuck at the point of getting channel binding to work. I have a ChannelBinding object from the TransportContext of my SslStream but the value is not what the server is expecting. Is there a different way or does .NET Core not implement tls-unique?

EDIT:

The code files in question can be found in my comment below.

Comment: This question lacks a lot of information and details for people outside your project

Comment: Sorry, the relevant code files are: https://github.com/ubiety/Ubiety.Xmpp.Core/blob/feature/scram/Ubiety.Xmpp.Core/Net/AsyncClientSocket.cs, https://github.com/ubiety/Ubiety.Xmpp.Core/blob/feature/scram/Ubiety.Xmpp.Core/Sasl/ScramProcessor.cs, https://github.com/ubiety/Ubiety.Xmpp.Core/blob/feature/scram/Ubiety.Xmpp.Core/Sasl/Scram/ClientFinalMessage.cs

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?